# "Server local connection provider has stopped listening" errors in SQL Server error log

Tags: sql-server, errors

We have started seeing the following errors appearing intermittently (between 1 and 5 a day on average) in the error logs on one of our SQL 2016 servers:

**Error: 26050, Severity: 17, State: 1. Server local connection provider has stopped listening on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQL16 ] due to a failure. Error: 0xe8, state: 4. The server will automatically attempt to re-establish listening.**

These are followed a few seconds later by:

**Server local connection provider has successfully re-established listening on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQL16 ].**

(SQL16 is the instance name of this server).

We do not appear to be getting any errors from the applications that use this server at the same time and as far as I am aware "\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQL16" is used by the Shared Memory protocol, which would indicate this was something that would only affect connections coming from the local server.

This server is part of an Availability Group and is the primary replica.  The databases are also log-shipped to a third server.  I have tried to look at any errors from Agent jobs etc. but cannot see anything obvious that ties in with the times we see these errors logged.

I am just curious as to what might cause these messages, as I have never seen them on any other servers.

Comment: Did you notice if the errors coincide with the running of logship copy/restore jobs on the 3rd server? Just because I found this similar bug reported.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32903662-pipe-timeout-errors-in-sql-server-2016-when-config

Comment: Here's a [similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193016/server-local-connection-provider-has-stopped-listening-on-local-pipe-due-to-a-fa) but it has no answers. There is a suggestion to try TCP connections as a workaround. This [blog post](https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/investigating-server-local-connection-provider-has-stopped-listening-on-pipesqllocalmssqlserver/) also shows the same issue with a few suggestions.

Comment: Do you have any way of monitoring the connections to see if it's a transport layer problem? Try leaving a ping running between the servers to see if anything odd shows up at the corresponding times `ping -t server1`.

Comment: [This feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32903662-pipe-timeout-errors-in-sql-server-2016-when-config) suggests the error is related to log shipping. Does the error only occur when log shipping jobs are running?